# No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10.10 в Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, установка, homebrew

При установке питон через homebrew появилась следующая проблема:
Для прохождения курса по питон мне нужна версия 3.9.10, а по факту стоит 3.10.10.
Я скачал через Homebrew версию 3.9.10. и ввел команду `brew unlink python@3.10.10`, чтобы потом ввести `brew link Python 3.9.10`. После ввода `brew unlink python@3.10.10` homebrew выдает следующую ошибку:

> No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10.10.

Переустановка питона, завершение и перезапуск терминала не помогли, работаю на маке.

Answer (score 0):

Для Mac OS Big Sur

я использовал команду

> brew install python

Она устанавливает питон 3.11
А вот команда, которая установит питон 3.9

> brew install python@3.9